# How to remove duplicate records from same table while displaying

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am having table DEMO

```
CUST_ID    DATE_ENQ
---------- ---------
30         28-APR-14 
31         27-APR-14 
30         27-APR-14
```

I want output something like this

```
COUNT(CUST_ID) DATE_ENQ
-------------- ---------
             2 27-APR-14 
             1 28-APR-14
```

Comment: Which is your database? MySql, SQL server, Orcle etc?

Comment: my database is Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Thiz**

```
select count(CUST_ID),TO_CHAR(DATE_ENQ,'DD-MON-YYYY') from demo group by TO_CHAR(DATE_ENQ,'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11165e/13/0)

Comment: There is no reason to use TO_DATE on DATE_ENQ (which should ideally already be a date).

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner juz see the output they want.. in that case two option there.. one group by DATE_ENQ and another one group by CUST_ID

Comment: No, you are confused somehow. TO_DATE converts a string type (CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2) into a DATETIME. What makes you think DATE_ENQ is a string type?

Comment: @Hitesh If that answer is correct mean make that as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM
   DEMO D1
WHERE
  D1.rowid >
   ANY (
     SELECT
        D2.rowid
     FROM
        DEMO D2
     WHERE
        D1.CUST_ID = D2.CUST_ID
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM tbl
WHERE rowid in
  (SELECT MIN(rowid)
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY DATE_ENQ);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee6c1/7)

Comment: Its not working....I dont want to actually delete the records , I just want to avoid duplicate records while displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select cust_id, min(date_enq) as Datez, COUNT(cust_id) as Custs
from tbl
group by cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the output as you have mentioned above. I have checked This is working

```
SELECT count(CUST_ID), DATE_ENQ FROM Demo GROUP BY DATE_ENQ;
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: @Hitesh: *What* is not working? Just saying "It is not working!" doesn't help anybody, and you should know that. This statement solves your problem perfectly. If it doesn't, then your description was incomplete. You can replace count(CUST_ID) by count(\*) because you are counting records actually and you can use TRUNC(DATE_ENQ) instead of DATE_ENQ for the case there are unwanted time parts in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCustomers,DATE_ENQ
FROM tableName
GROUP BY DATE_ENQ
ORDER BY TotalCustomers
```